# Can an offset of an unassigned partition be committed by KafkaConsumer.commitSync/commitAsync

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

```
KafkaConsumer.commitSync(Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> offsets)
```

Can above method be used to commit offset of an unassigned TopicPartition ?

I know `ConsumerRebalanceListener.onPartitionsRevoked` is the right place to do final offset commit before TopicPartition rebalance.

But if I commit offset of a partition which consumer does not have in its assigned list now, e.g. it lost it after rebalance, how will Kafka treat it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will throw the following Exception:

```sh
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Offset commit cannot be completed since the consumer is not part of an active group for auto partition assignment; it is likely that the consumer was kicked out of the group.
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.sendOffsetCommitRequest(ConsumerCoordinator.java:1109)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.commitOffsetsSync(ConsumerCoordinator.java:976)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.commitSync(KafkaConsumer.java:1511)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.commitSync(KafkaConsumer.java:1459)
```